# Removing duplicate usernames, and combining columns of duplicates

Tags: bash, awk

right now I have a few different lists, I'll try to explain it all best I can.

List 1 looks like the following:

```
user1,host1:port1
user2,host2:port2
user1,host3:port3
```

I run a look-up against a database for the usernames and return the following:

```
user1   email1
user2   email2
user1   email1
```

In my example, both files have duplicate users, and emails. However, the hosts and ports may all be different. What would be the most efficient way to get output that looks like the following:

```
user1   email1    host1:port1, host3:port3
user2   email2    host2:port2
```

I'm assuming advanced usage of awk, but frankly something like this goes over my head. Any help/point in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file1
user1,host1:port1
user2,host2:port2
user1,host3:port3

$ cat file2
user1   email1
user2   email2
user1   email1

$ cat tst.awk                
BEGIN{ FS="[[:space:],]+" }
NR==FNR { user2hosts[$1][$2]; next }
{ user2email[$1] = $2 }
END {
   for (user in user2email) {
       printf "%s\t%s\t", user, user2email[user]
       sep = ""
       for (host in user2hosts[user]) {
           printf "%s%s", sep, host
           sep = ", "
       }
       print ""
   }
}

$ gawk -f tst.awk file1 file2
user1   email1  host1:port1, host3:port3
user2   email2  host2:port2
```

The above uses GNU awk 4.* for 2D arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Using this awk:

```
awk -F '[, ]+' 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0; next}
$1 in a {
   if (!seen[a[$1]])
      seen[a[$1]] = $2;
   else
      seen[a[$1]] = seen[a[$1]] ", " $2
}
END { for (i in seen) print i, seen[i]}' list2 list1
user2   email2 host2:port2
user1   email1 host1:port1, host3:port3
```